# Bottom align logos and top align titles

Tags: css, layout, css-tables, graphical-logo

I'm trying to achieve a layout for a grid of logos where the logos are bottom aligned to a common baseline and the titles, below the logos, are top aligned. Both are centrally aligned horizontally.

[I can achieve this easily using tables](http://jsfiddle.net/xtj3y/), but semantically, I think that I'd prefer to use divs. FYI, I'm using the Bootstrap framework.

I've tried all kinds of CSS combinations, but I was always running into conflicts with `display` and `position` attributes.

I'm sure that there are JavaScript solutions too, which I want to use only as a last resort.

Can anyone think of a way to do this in CSS without using tables or JS?

Comment: Did you try CSS `display:table`, `table-cell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div{
    display: inline-table;
    max-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
div img{
  display: table-row;
}
div h3{
  display: table-row;
}
```

See the updated fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/xtj3y/3/

Comment: Please take the time to format and ensure your code is valid.  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/xtj3y/6/

Comment: `alt` is a required attribute for `<img>` tags. http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/img/alt#alt__li3

Comment: @FC' Thanks for answering, but the images aren't center aligned.

Comment: @kdev : They should be. I'm on firefox 22 and everything's fine.

Seems to fail in webkit, just add 'margin: 0 auto;' to the img

Comment: @FC' Took a while to iron out a few issues but I got there thanks to your answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I changed every tr, td and table element to a div and added a class "table" to the outer div. After that I used the following css:

```css
.table {
    display: table;
}

.table > div {
    display: table-row;
}

.table > div > div {
    width:33%;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
.logos div {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.titles td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

That will look like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/xtj3y/4/

EDIT:

Sorry, didn't see your question on time.
I made a change. The downside is that you have to use absolute heights, instead of variable heights.

see:
http://jsfiddle.net/xtj3y/18/

Comment: I thought that was it but the semantic issues aren't really resolved. The flow of the information makes no sense unless it's seen visually. That's why I wanted to get away from using tables.

Comment: I read over the semantic issue. Sorry about that. I changed it. See the EDIT part.

Comment: This still doesn't work. The images aren't bottom aligned on the second row. The accepted answer works and has cleaner markup. Thanks for your efforts though.